# How to unmount the component in React Naitve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a splash screen with progress bar. The whole function of the splash screen is to check whether user is available and if yes, it will redirect to Dashboard else Signup form. I am using redux action to calculate progress bar value and login check.

Here is my Progress Bar Action Code :

```
export const progressBarLevel = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    this.progress = 0;
    dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: 0 });
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({ type: INDETERMINATE, payload: false });
       const interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.progress += Math.random()/5;
            if(this.progress > 1){
                this.progress = 1;
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            return dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: this.progress });
        },250)
    },500)
  }
}
```

And my login Check Action :

```
export const loginCheck = () => {
return async (dispatch) => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGIN_TOKEN);
    let userUid = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_UID);
    if(token && userUid) {
        dispatch({ type: VALID_LOGIN_AVAILABLE, payload: token });
        dispatch({ type: VALID_UID_AVAILABLE, payload: userUid });
    }
    else {
        dispatch({ type: NO_VALID_LOGIN_AVAILABLE, payload: token });
    }
  }
};
```

So, by using these i am populating the needs. And i am using componentDidMount and willUpdate to perfom actions.

My componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.loginCheck();
   this.props.progressBarLevel();
}
```

My componentDidUpdate():

```
componentDidUpdate() {
this.mounted = true;
    if(this.props.progressed === 1) {
        if(this.props.token === null) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('WelcomeAuth')
        }
        else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
        }
    }
```

}.

So, over all everything is working correctly, but when there is no user availble. The pages get redirect to "WelcomeAuth" ( actually its correct) But, when i enter something , it again redirects to "Beginning of the page", As a welcome page. So then, i should be clicking on signup button and enter next word, the again it goes back to  Welcome page.

How to stop the splashscreen component ? As its work is to redirect thats it, after redirect, the splash screen should be unmounted so that, it wont work on background ?

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

First create a action to reset the navigation stact

```
const homeAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'HomeScreen' })],
});
```

then navigate using dispatch

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(homeAction);
```

here all other components will be removed and only HomeScreen will be in the navigation stack